# How do I automatically save a KeePass entry attachment at unlock / delete it at lock

Tags: keepass

When I unlock my database, I'd like to be able to save an attached file from a particular KeePass entry to a particular location on my local drive... then delete that file when the database is locked or closed so that it's not available when my database is locked (some tools need secrets in files, but I only want that available when I've got my database unlocked).

I thought I remembered something like that in the past, but after a few days of searching documentation, I cannot find a way to do it (or remember the situation/search that allowed me to think it existed in the past).

I had hoped there was a Trigger with action setup: I can see a Trigger for opened database, but none for closed; and I cannot see an action that saves attachments.

Or, if not that, is there an existing plugin that does that?  (Or can such a thing be done in the KPScript scripting plugin?  if so, any hints as to which commands I should start researching?)

---

### update

My question was actually an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  I really should have said, "I need to have a file that is only accessible when my KeePass database is unlocked, and is removed or encrypted or otherwise inaccessible when my database is locked or closed; can I accomplish that with KeePass using triggers or a plugin or some other means?"

Comment: I gave you a very full answer and it was downvoted and deleted You cannot save a single entry.

Comment: @John, thanks for trying.  Too bad the details were deleted before I saw it.

Comment: With lack of detailed responses in the last day , I have asked again ("crossposted") in the sourceforge repo's forum (https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/822f0aeb2a/) ... if there's a good answer there, I'll summarize it here

Comment: My answer had all the information on it . Do you wish me to undelete the answer ?

Comment: Probably don't bother.  So far in the repo's help forum, it looks like it would require writing a whole plugin to do what I wanted.  I'll have to figure out an alternative.  So the right "answer" would be "you cannot with existing tools".  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Despite of the discussion, I think you are actually creating a security nightmare that way: A deleted file can be restored in many cases, did you know? Also if the program crashes, the file won't be deleted, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question as originally phrased was actually an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

The answer to my question as originally stated was "No, it is not possible".

The answer to the question I *really* needed answered was [supplied by "Paul" in the repo's forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/822f0aeb2a/):

> If you keep the attachment in a separate encrypted self extracting file via 7zip, you can get KeePass to supply the password to decrypt with a trigger.

Expanding on that: With the file encrypted on my local disk (*not* as an entry attachment), it is unaccessible by any who don't have the password.  Then, in KeePass, I can define a [Trigger](https://keepass.info/help/v2/triggers.html) that occurs when the database is opened (which includes unlock as well), with an action which runs an external command -- specifically, the 7zip or gpg or similar utility to unencrypt the file; using the [reference syntax](https://keepass.info/help/base/fieldrefs.html), I can pass the password from a particular Entry in KeePass to be used for the unlock.  I can even include a Filter which will prevent the action from running if the encrypted file is missing.

To clean up when I lock or close the database, another trigger can be used on the closed-database event, which deletes the unencrypted file (or re-encrypts the file... whichever works better with the encryption/unencryption application, depending on whether the decryption replaced the file or just created a second file that was unencrypted).